# Testing antlr4 visitor rules

Tags: unit-testing, java-7, antlr4, table-driven

I've got a fairly complicated antlr4 grammar that utilizes a visitor pattern.  I'd like to test parts of the visitor.  What's a good way to test individual visit rules?

My visitor has tons of rules like this that I want to test:

```
@Override
public Object visitQux(ExclParser.QuxContext ctx) {
  return visitChildren(ctx);
}
```

And my test code basically is the following:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(stdError, false /* autoFlush */, "UTF-8")
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);

MyLexer lexer = new MyLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
MyParser parser = new MyParser(tokens);

parser.removeErrorListeners();
MyErrorListener errorListener = new MyErrorListener(ps, filename);
parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);

MyVisitor visitor = new MyVisitor();
visitor.setParser(filename, parser, errorListener);
ParseTree tree = parser.qux();   // <--- This is the line I want to vary.
Object result = visitor.visit(tree);
assertThat(describeExpectation(), result, equalTo(this.expectedOutput));
```

Ideally I would be able to test any visitor using a parameterized test.  But to get the parse tree I want to visit (parser.qux) I can't specify any variant of qux() in a table because parser.qux() is not static.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I created an example project on how ANTLR-visitors could be tested (using Mockito&TestNG). [The full source code can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/yankee42/antlr-visitor-test-demo). Here are the most important parts:

```java
public class MyVisitor extends DemoBaseVisitor<String> {
    @Override
    public String visitPlus(final DemoParser.PlusContext ctx) {
        return visit(ctx.left) + " PLUS " + visit(ctx.right);
    }

    @Override
    public String visitLiteralNumber(final DemoParser.LiteralNumberContext ctx) {
        return ctx.getText();
    }
}
```

Any my test for that visitor:

```java
public class MyVisitorTest {
    private final MyVisitor myVisitor = new MyVisitor();

    @Test
    public void visitPlus_joinsOperatorsWithWordPLUSAsSeparator() throws Exception {
        // setup
        final DemoParser.PlusContext plusNode = mock(DemoParser.PlusContext.class);
        plusNode.left = mockForVisitorResult(DemoParser.ExpressionContext.class, "2");
        plusNode.right = mockForVisitorResult(DemoParser.ExpressionContext.class, "4");

        // execution
        final String actual = myVisitor.visitPlus(plusNode);

        // evaluation
        assertEquals(actual, "2 PLUS 4");
    }

    private<T extends RuleContext> T mockForVisitorResult(final Class<T> nodeType, final String visitResult) {
        final T mock = mock(nodeType);
        when(mock.accept(myVisitor)).thenReturn(visitResult);
        return mock;
    }

    @Test
    public void visitLiteralNumber_returnsTextValueOfNumber() throws Exception {
        // setup
        final DemoParser.LiteralNumberContext literalNumberNode = mock(DemoParser.LiteralNumberContext.class);
        when(literalNumberNode.getText()).thenReturn("42");

        // execution
        final String actual = myVisitor.visitLiteralNumber(literalNumberNode);

        // evaluation
        assertEquals(actual, "42");
    }
}
```

In your special example where you have a method which calls visitChildren() your would test that calling that method returns the aggregated result of visiting all child nodes (what the aggregation is depends on your implementation of the `aggregateResult` method).

Answer (score 0):

Reflection may be the right answer here:

```
Method method = MyParser.class.getDeclaredMethod("qux");
ParseTree tree = (ParseTree) method.invoke(parser);
```

is a suitable replacement for:

```
ParseTree tree = parser.qux();
```